# How to assign different color codes in android?

Tags: android

I have to draw a pie chart in my project and for that I have found a very good [example](http://tutorials-android.blogspot.in/2011/05/how-create-pie-chart-in-android.html).
Now I want to change the colors of the pie-chart. For that I have found [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html). But when I keep those colors it is not effecting. How can I change my constants(colors) in the below line

```
int colors[] = { -6777216, -16776961, -16711681, -12303292, -7829368 };
```

I want to keep forest green and red color. How can I keep those colors? Please help me regarding this. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If your question is How do I add custom color definitions to an android application, answer is [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color).

Answer (score 0):

[android.graphics.Color](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html) has static methods that create colors from (A)RGB and HSV representations.  Colors which are equal to hexadecimal ARGB literals, which you can also use: 0xAARRGGBB

The line of you've pasted here  represents colors with decimal numerals and thus frustrates your ability to perform basic source-level operations on the colors it represents.  *It damns the example it appears in.*  So, forget that line, and look elsewhere for pie chart examples, and when you next want to use one color rather than another in your program, you'll just do so, without having to ask anyone how.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
int color_red = Color.parseColor("#FF0000");

int color_green = Color.parseColor("#008000");

int my_color[] = {color_red, color_green};


for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

your_variable.your_action = my_color[i];

}
```